# How to apply VBA code to all Powerpoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am interested in applying the following VBA code to all slides in my powerpoint presentation. The code below resizes my table to the exact specifications I need. Do you have any advice on how to make this apply throughout my presentation? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ResizeAlign()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 216
    .Width = 864
    .Left = 48
    .Top = 198
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following macro will loop through each slide within the active presentation.  Then, for each slide, it will loop through each shape within the slide until it finds a table, and then it formats the table.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ResizeAlignPresentation()
    Dim currentSlide As Slide
    For Each currentSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        ResizeAlignSlide currentSlide
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeAlignSlide(ByVal target As Slide)
    Dim currentShape As Shape
    For Each currentShape In target.Shapes
        If currentShape.Type = msoTable Then
            ResizeAlignTable currentShape
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeAlignTable(ByVal table As Shape)
    With table
        Debug.Assert .Type = msoTable 'if code breaks here, we have a bug!
        .Height = 216
        .Width = 864
        .Left = 48
        .Top = 198
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That `o` prefix is useless, wrong, and actively harmful. If you haven't read [this excellent article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) from the author of the VBA language specifications (and CEO of Stack Overflow), I'd warmly recommend it. That prefixing habit is called *Systems Hungarian*, and it was nothing more than a big huge stupid misunderstanding - the inventor of *Hungarian Notation* / *Apps Hungarian* never intended for anyone to encode the data type of a variable in its name. Would be nice if SO answers stopped propagating it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Thanks Mathieu, I'll read the article as soon as I get a chance.   Cheers!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Very interesting article.  I wasn't aware of the history behind that sort of notation.  And so I've now edited my post.  Thank you very much for pointed it out to me.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: First time I read it, it was an eye opener - felt like I had been robbed of so many years.. all these CS teachers perpetuating the lie.. I must have linked to that article a thousand times, very few come back and thank me for it! Cheers!

Comment: I've taken the liberty to rename the disemvoweled identifiers and [flatten the arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) - feel free to rollback if you don't agree with the edit =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for renaming the identifiers.  It makes things very clear.  Also, thanks for flattening the arrow code. It makes it easier to follow.  And thanks for another interesting article.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have upped the last answer with this code I created (in need). I needed to run through all SlideMasters, all slides, all textboxes and put them on top. So they will always be in front of pictures etc.

```
Sub SetInFront()
Dim m, s, t, ma, sl, te

Set ma = ActivePresentation.Designs
For Each m In ma
    Set sl = m.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    For Each s In sl
        Set te = s.Shapes
        For Each t In te
            If t.HasTextFrame Then
                t.ZOrder 0
            End If
        Next t
    Next s
Next m

End Sub
```